# Preventing battery from constant charging in Ultrabook

Tags: linux, debian, power-management, battery

I'm running Debian Jessie (64-bit) on a newly-acquired Samsung Ultrabook NP900X3E, so far everything's working as it's supposed to.
However, the battery life is *okay*, but not great. Therefore, I wondered whether there is some command for Debian to "ignore" the battery when plugged in (=setting a threshold). Since the battery cannot be removed easily (without a screw-driver, that is), any way to prevent my battery from increasing heat by being subject to constant charging while on AC would be most welcome - so far I only know this was possible for Thinkpads.
Of course, please do correct in case I misunderstand or miss something completely here.

Best regards,
T.

Answer (score 0):

1. do not notbook/laptops set up like this.. if on a cord it chares the battery when it id full then it just keeps it full no harm is being done, and still uses the cord to use elec to power the device....
2. I had a netbook that would work without the battery in it, on a cord.
3. battery over heating ?? not a good thing. that'd be a sign of a defective maybe blow up battery condistion, I'd think.